# Fragmentation of related records in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a table which contains previous product purchases of a user like so:

```
ID | ProductName | UserID
 1 | Grapes      | 3455
 2 | Water       | 1944
 3 | Bread       | 3455
 4 | Milk        | 3455
 ...
```

As you can see in the example above, user `3455` has bought grapes, bread and milk. If I wanted to retrieve all the products a user has bought, I would have to find each of the records which has user `3455`.

Would storing all the products which are from user `3455` together speed up searching for these records like defragmenting a hard drive? And if so, would the process of deleting the old records and readding them to the end of the database be a waste of processing power?

Comment: No not a good idea. Just add an index to `UserID` and that is pretty much like storing the rows together

Comment: It is better to use Normalisation instead of the small performance aspect. That will make your programming tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to get the information you want is to have an index on `t(UserId, ProductName)`.  This is a *covering* index for the following query:

```
select ProductName
from t
where UserId = 3455;
```

The means that all the columns needed by the query are in the index, and in the proper order.  So, the query optimizer can resolve the query using only the index.  This should be quite fast.